Firestore Rule with hasAny is not working
I have following firestore rule, which is not working:
allow read: if (get(resource.data.chat).data.users).hasAny(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admins)

What I want is that there is a messages collection and there is a chats collection. Messages Document has a reference to a chat document and that chat document has an array of user doc references. User also has a field called admins, which is also a list of user document references. Now, I want the user that is sending the request, to be able to read  the messages doc, if any of the user in chat's users field is in the admins field of that user.
This should be working, but I am still getting the permission denied error.
Why would that be?

What is the query you are doing on your client side? Maybe you are not properly filtering it with a where clause. Remember that security rules are not filters so if your query is potentially returning documents not allowed to be read, then the whole query will fail with a "Missing or Insufficient Permissions" error. Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query
If you are filtering properly, then I don't know. I am having a similar issue regarding hasAny and arrays as variables, I don't know if maybe yours and mine are related. Could you manage to solve it?
My issue: Firestore rule get() work in the simulator but not in the app
